# What is this explosion sound effect?

Tags: sound-effects

I am looking for that explosion sound effect used at 0:41 in that video:

Comment: …and what has your research so far shown you? What stopped you from being able to reproduce it yourself?

Comment: @Tetsujin Its probably mix of bolt and explosion sound. I am trying to add soprano to explosion or continuing searching for that specific sound.